# Problem uploading files with other parameters

Tags: java, spring

I am trying to upload multiple files with other parameters from the client to the server.

My AJAX is:

```
files: (binary)
files: (binary)
arrStr: [{"name":"aa","file":"Test PDF 2.pdf","status":"on"},{"name":"bb","file":"TEST PDF.pdf","status":"on"}]
```

And my controllers is:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/saveUploadFileListing", consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
    public String saveUploadFileListing(
            @RequestParam(value="files", required = false) MultipartFile [] file,
            @RequestParam(value="arrStr") FileManagementSaveWrapper arrStr) {
        List<FileManagementSaveDTO> files = arrStr.getFileManagement();
```

And my FileManagementSaveWrapper is:

```
@Data
public class FileManagementSaveWrapper {
    private List <FileManagementSaveDTO> fileManagement;
}
```

And my FileManagementSaveDTO is:

```
@Data
public class FileManagementSaveDTO {
    private String name;
    private String file;
    private String status;
}
```

But the problem is:

```
[org.springframework.web.method.annotation.MethodArgumentConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'com.nera.nms.dto.FileManagementSaveWrapper'; 
nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'com.nms.dto.FileManagementSaveWrapper': no matching editors or conversion strategy found]
```

I am not sure why the String cannot be conveted to the wrapper class.

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: From your AJAX, arrStr looks like an array, have you tried in Controller: @RequestParam(value="arrStr") List <FileManagementSaveDTO> arrStr

Comment: I got this error:Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.util.List'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'com..nms.dto.FileManagementSaveDTO': no matching editors or conversion strategy found